# pylint warnings regarding global variables and invalid names

Tags: python, global, pylint

I've written some python code that has some global constants and global variables (global within a module).  Some of the global variables get changed later in the module by functions (e.g., a func that gets command line arguments).  The code works just fine, but pylint complains:

(1) the global variables are invalid names because it is outside a function and expects it to be all caps.

(2) pylint complains about using the global keyword

Here's an example:

```
DEFAULT_GLOBAL_VAR1 = some value

global_var1 = DEFAULT_GLOBAL_VAR1

def get_cmd_line_args():

    global global_var1
    global_var1 = <cmd line value>
```

... more defs follow that change some of the other global variables.

(1) Why does Python/pylint not recognize lowercase global module variable names?  I know that global variables are frowned upon, but sometimes they are necessary.  What's the Pythonic way to deal with the pylint warnings about invalid names on global variables?

(2) I dislike the idea of disabling pylint warnings; is there another way, a better way to handle this scenario?

Comment: pylint wants it all caps because it thinks it's a constant and hence it should be all caps to indicate that because python has no concept of constants. Also does your `global_var1` needs to be declared outside the function. You should make it function scope. It more functions are changing it, well then they shouldn't. You can read cmd line values in your function and return it from the function instead of having a global variable and changing it. Also you can provide the error code of pylint and it will be easier for us to guess why that error is happening.